# TensorArray stack operation throws ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to use a `TensorArray` in a `while_loop`, where each iteration of the loop fills one item in the `TensorArray`. A minimal example below is shown:

```
ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(size=4, tensor_array_name='output_ta', dtype=tf.float32)
time = tf.constant(0)

def _call(time, ta):
    ta.write(time, tf.constant([1.,2.,3.,4.]))
    return (time+1, ta)

_, t_out = tf.while_loop(
    cond=lambda time, _: time < 4,
    body=_call,
    loop_vars=(time, ta)
)
```

Now, this code runs fine. However, as soon as I try to do anything with `t_out`, it gives an error e.g.

```
t_out.stack()
>>>  Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Edit: This only seems to happen in Eager mode. If anyone knows how I can fix it so it works in eager mode that would be great.

Comment: What version of tensorflow as you using? I just tried your example with 1.10 and it works fine - only differences was I changed `tensor_array_ops.TensorArray` to `tf.TensorArray`

Answer (score 0):

```py
ta = ta.write(time, tf.constant([1.,2.,3.,4.]))
```

Comment: A little explanation would make this code-only answer better.